# Paginating filtered records

Tags: php, pagination, bolt-cms

I have a content filter which is based off of some GET variables to get records of a certain category and list them. If the number of records exceeds the records per page setting then ideally I would like to paginate them. My code for retrieving the records works like so:

Request URL: `/discussions?categories[]=news&categories[]=events`

In my twig code I have the following:

```
{% set categories = app.request.get('categories') %}
{% if categories is not empty %}
    {% set filter = categories|join(' || ')  %}
    {% setcontent records = 'discussions' where { discussions: filter } limit 6  allowpaging %}
{% endif %}
```

I then have `{{ pager('discussions') }}` at the end of the page.

It shows the correct number of pages to iterate through but the target URL is inaccurate (missing the GET parameters) and so when going to the next page the records are no longer filtered therefore returning all. Is there a way to append my filter parameters?

I am aware that it's possible to setup routes based on the taxonomy, i.e. `/taxonomy/option` and have that list results and paginate them. However this method falls short once you start to introduce multiple filter options which can be used singularly or in combination.

**Documentation**
Fetching records: http://docs.bolt.cm/content-fetching
Pager: http://docs.bolt.cm/content-paging

Comment: They mention you can create your own pager, simply by copying `/app/theme_defaults/_sub_pager.twig`. After that, just modify the following line: https://github.com/bolt/site/blob/master/app/theme_defaults/_sub_pager.twig#L17